# Convert each item in array separately

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to convert each item in an array so they look like newusers below.

```
var userids=['792','796','788','676' etc...]
```

So it looks like this.

```
var newusers=["792"]["796"]["788"]["676"]etc...
```

Any input really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: That is not jQuery, and the result is not valid syntax in JavaScript either. But look at [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join?v=example).

Comment: Yeah, @trincot is right, your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join`, or `JSON.stringify` in combination (or not) with `map` to get some string format for an array. For example:

```js
var userids=[792,796,788,676];

var str = userids.map(function (v) { return '["' + v + '"]' }).join('');

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Yes thats looks right, but I get an error on this: var str = userids.map(v => '["' + v + '"]').join('');

Comment: I suppose your are on Internet Exploder? I adjusted it to only use ES5, not ES6.

Answer (score 0):

convert string to array

Here is the example

```
var userids= "792,796,788,676";
```

var newuserid = userids.split(",");
console.log(newuserid);

http://jsbin.com/xobitadama/edit?js,console

Comment: Thanks, but I only get ["792", "796", "788", "676"] and I need ["792"] ["796"] ["788"][ "676"]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.map()` to transform each user id into an array and `String` to convert each number to a string:

```js
var userids = [792, 796, 788, 676];

var res = userids.map(function (id) {
  return [String(id)];
});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Yes but without the the left and right brackets, just the ones inside, and the comma in-between :-)

Comment: Yes a string, sorry my array is not numbers it is string values :-)

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson, that has nothing to do with whether the output should be string or array.

Comment: @Claes Try editing your question so it makes sense. What you are asking for is not valid Javascript.